# Creating Dynamic SQL Query to join multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset in SQl which includes huge numbers of tables (more than 2000).
Within these tables, I have a main table called
'main_table', that includes some parameters and one of them is the key named 'id'. I have also a
table called 'Tables_name', which consists of the name of the tables (around 500 tables name) that I want to join to the main
table (main_table). Each table has two parameters (id and value).

Basically I want to left join all the tables (in the dataset) which their names are in 'Tables_name',
based on their 'id'. I need a query that automatically join those tables
(and creat a new table having all parameters from the main_table and values of those joint tables)
based on thier key which is 'id'. They all have the 'id' as the key parametrs.

```
   main_table:
     id, name, date, category, age, brand, number 

   Tables_name:
              tablxcd
              tableasd
              tablefgd
                  ..
                  ..
                  ..
   tablxcd:
           id,value
   tablasd:
           id,value
   tablegd: 
           id,value
```

My desired table should be like this:

```
   output_table:
               id, name, date, category, age, brand, number, tablxcd_value, tablasd_value, ...
```

It should be left join, because there might be some ids which are not matched for all tables, so in the output table
the values of those rows which are not matched should be zero. I have tried this :

```
 SELECT mn.Id,mn.name
  ,mn.Date
  ,mn.brand
  ,mn.category
  ,xcs.value as tablxcd_value
  ,asd.value as tablasd_value
  FROM [mydatabase].[dbo].[main_table] mn LEFT JOIN [mydatabase].[dbo]. 
 [tablxcd] xcs ON mn.Id=xcd.Id
 LEFT JOIN [mydatabase].[dbo].[tablasd] asd ON asd.Id=mn.Id 
 where mn.Date > '2018-01-01'
```

But this is manual, and some how it is not possible to put all the 500 tables' name here.

Comment: This sounds like you have a major design flaw, if I am honest.

Comment: What did you try so far and what was the issue with that? If it is not so late you should consider redesign your database, because 2000 joined tables sounds like a design flaw.

Comment: No, actually it is not a design flaw. The database is already there and I need to extract some tables with their parameters from it. I have updated the above question and mentioned what I tried so far.

Comment: @TomKlarin, just because the database already exists, doesn't mean the design is not flawed. 500 tables in a query is a red-flag as is the need to resort to dynamic SQL. FWIW, created the tables (sans data) and query in your question and the actual execution plan shows over 14 seconds just to compile the query: `<QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="4696" CompileTime="14287" CompileCPU="14287" CompileMemory="30064">`. I'm glad I'm not the DBA supporting this app.

Comment: Don't worry too much about the database design.  Yes, it is bad.  But you have to live with what you got and fix what you they let you fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will assemble a dynamic query from a list of tables.  It assumes that Tables_name has an IDENTITY.  If it does not, then create a temp table with an IDENTITY and use it instead. It also assumes that the tables names do not contain special characters or use reserved words.

```
DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(MAX), @strJoins NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', @strColumns NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @i SMALLINT = 1, @imax SMALLINT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.tables_name)

WHILE @i <= @imax
BEGIN

SELECT @strColumns = @strColumns + CHAR(10)  + ', ' + name + '.value as ' + name + 'value' FROM dbo.tables_name WHERE Id = @i
SELECT @strJoins = @strJoins + CHAR(10) + 'LEFT JOIN ' + name + ' ON ' + name + '.Id = main.Id' FROM dbo.tables_name WHERE Id = @i

SET @i += 1
END

SELECT @qry = 'SELECT main.* ' + @strColumns + CHAR(10) + 'FROM main ' + @strJoins

PRINT @qry
```

Comment: I added a column 'ID' as an identity in the 'Tables_name' table. Here, instead of "+ name +", what should I put? should I use the name of the columns from the main table?

Comment: I would also concern myself with the max size of a SQL command (~65k) ?

Comment: RE: "I added a column 'ID' as an identity in the 'Tables_name' table. Here, instead of "+ name +", what should I put? should I use the name of the columns from the main table? "  Script will run as-is with the IDENTITY.

Comment: RE: "I would also concern myself with the max size of a SQL command (~65k) ?"  Could happen.  But 65k is a lot of JOINs.

Comment: "65k is a lot of joins" - Indeed... 2000+ is a lot of tables, but that is c. 30 characters per join statement - not really enough I would suggest ?

Comment: @BlackLight Actually, only 500 JOINs, but you make a good point.  I have seen 800 to 1000 lines of sql from ORMs for a single call to sp_executesql (we have an especially evil one called nHibernate that was used years ago but remains in the app wreaking havoc on performance).  So, I would go with it as is for the first attempt.  But, IF the script throws an error, just cut the Tables_name table in half and run the code twice.  Good comment.

Comment: Yes indeed. it is a lot. The above code works, but '@strColumns' gives me only the first 70 tables name to join.

Comment: Might not be the cause (cannot see anything else obvious), but you know your "print" will truncate at 4000 characters ? Stick in a "print len(@qry)" and see what you have.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks

Comment: @Jim: I've also seen ORMs produce "statement is too complex" exceptions - which is what immediately sprung to mind here.